# Regex htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to check inside my htaccess if the user does not have a cookie named XXX with the value YYY. I am using this line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(^|;)?XXX=YYY(;|$)
```

It works fine. I just dont understand why do I need to use the "?" symbol? Is there any reason? And why the code below does not work (it shows a 500 error message in my server):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(^|; )XXX=YYY(;|$)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right pattern to check for a cookie and it's value is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(^|\s)XXX=YYY(;|$) [NC]
```

This will ensure that cookie name `XXX` is either at start or after a white space.

You're getting 500 error because you have an unescaped space in your 2nd rule condition.

Comment: do I need to escape space?

Comment: Yes you do, space is considered a token delimiter in `mod_rewrite`

Comment: Amazing :) I will accep tyour answer after 3 minutes

Comment: Do you agree with me that if there is a space inside the content of the cookie your code will fail cause it may think that the name of a cookie can be inside the value of another cookie?

Comment: I was reading some posts in the internet and I think your original code was correct and using the symbol ; is redundant. I read that inside the value of a cookie should never exist a whitespace and if it exist it should be converted to %20!

Comment: oh great, let me roll back my change. Thanks for checking.